# Change name of emailed document to Email title

Tags: 2010, document, email-enabled-library

I email a spreadsheet to SharePoint and I want to save the document not with its original name but with a name built from the title of the email - any ideas please?

For example: doc name is fhdhfjd1234.xls and email title "Cost Centre Report - TYEF". The name I want to see in SharePoint is "Cost Centre Report - TYEF.xls".

I also want to be able to populate the file metadeta using the email content too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheena,

You can use [SPEmailEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx) for your requirement..

And the following should help you

[How to enable an Event Handler to intercept upload from email in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-enable-an-event-handler-to-intercept-upload-from-email-in-document-librar)

There is a possibility that when you write SPEmailEventReceiver the attachment doesn't upload directly, in that case you need to programmatically add an item (attachment) to document library and set metadata..