# Email Attachments as Individual Items in Document Library

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, document-library, email

There are many ways to receive this outcome, but they are not working exactly how I imagine.

Issue: I created a document library and I have emails going into the library according to subject.  The emails have a lot of attachments and no consistency with the subject names.  The next best thing would be to have the attachments into the document library by individual items.  For example, email #1 has four attachments.  I want the four documents to appear in the document as so

```
Attachment #1
Attachment #2
Attachment #3
Attachment #4
```

Is this possible? Would I create a workflow to get the job done?

I have tried using Internet Explorer options to drag and drop into the library but the attachments are still inside the email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use email event receivers for this. Check a similar question here  : [How to enable an Event Handler to intercept upload from email in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-enable-an-event-handler-to-intercept-upload-from-email-in-document-librar)

Comment: Thank you, Akhoy.  Would I use the "email events" event receiver?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. You'll have to choose the email events event receiver to add to your project.

Comment: Would a workflow be easier?  If so, which workflow would I use? Thanks!

Comment: Imo workflow would be tougher than this. And Afaik, no OOTB workflow step exists which can read emails and find out attachments from them.